# SQL Server. Table resides in a filegroup which is not online

Tags: sql, sql-server, referential-integrity, filegroup, database-integrity

I have such a table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    Id1 INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Value VARCHAR(50)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE Table2 (
    Id2 INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Value VARCHAR(50)
) ON [FILE_GROUP_2]
GO

CREATE TABLE Table3Link (
    Id3 INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Id1 INT NOT NULL,
    Id2 INT NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE Table3Link ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Table3Link_Table1 FOREIGN KEY(Id1)
REFERENCES Table1 (Id1)
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE Table3Link ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Table3Link_Table2 FOREIGN KEY(Id2)
REFERENCES Table2 (Id2)
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
```

Filegroup `[PRIMARY]` is online.

Filegroup `[FILE_GROUP_2]` is offline.

When I run query `select * from Table1`, I get following error:

> The query processor is unable to produce a plan for the table or view
>   'Table2' because the table resides in a filegroup which is not online.

How can I ignore this integrity validation without making `[FILE_GROUP_2]` online?

Comment: I've tried to create a database with two FG and I've tried to run your script. Executing the select on Table1 works for me. I get that error when executing `SELECT * FROM Table2`, but this is obvious since the table is on the offline FG. What SQL Server Version are you speaking about? I've scripted the snippet on a SQL Server 2012 SP2 (+ hotfix).

Comment: [tag:sql-server-2012]
  When I created new test database, there was no such an error.
But on production database it occurred that `select top 355209 * from Table1` works fine. Whereas query `select top 355210 * from Table1` returns an error.
Other strange behaviour is that query from another database works without errors: `use other_db; go; select * from error_db.dbo.Table1`.

Comment: Yes, it's strange.. I've sql server 2012 too, but I cannot reproduce the issue.